# How do I implement the Triplet Loss in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to implement Google's Facenet paper:

[image]

First of all, is it possible to implement this paper using the Sequential API of Keras or should I go for the Graph API?

In either case, could you please tell me how do I pass the custom loss function `tripletLoss` to the model compile and how do I receive the `anchor embedding`, `positive embedding` and the `negative embedding` as parameters to calculate the loss?

Also, what should be the second parameter Y in model.fit(), I do not have any in this case...

Comment: Hey! Where you able to implement Facenet on Keras? I'm working on a project that needs just this and was wondering if you were able to pull this off...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/369) explains how to create a custom objective (loss) in Keras:

```
def dummy_objective(y_true, y_pred):
    return 0.5  # your implem of tripletLoss here

model.compile(loss=dummy_objective, optimizer='adadelta')
```

Regarding the `y` parameter of `.fit()`, since you are the one handling it in the end (the `y_true` parameter of the objective function is taken from it), I would say you can pass whatever you need that can fit through Keras plumbing. And maybe a dummy vector to pass dimension checks if your really don't need any supervision.

Eventually, as to how to implement this particular paper, looking for `triplet` or `facenet` in [Keras doc](https://keras.io/) didn't return anything. So you'll probably have to either implement it yourself or find someone who has.